# Meteor Cloudinary and lepozepo:cloudinary

Tags: meteor, cloudinary

I have setup a barbone meteor app in order to test lepozepo:cloudinary package.

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

  $.cloudinary.config({cloud_name:"name"})

  Template.hello.events({
    'click button': function () {
      // increment the counter when button is clicked
      Session.set('counter', Session.get('counter') + 1);
    },

    "change input[type='file']": function (event) {
      files = event.currentTarget.files
      Cloudinary.upload(files,{err:function(e){console.info(e)},res:function(e){console.info(e)}})

    }

  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
Cloudinary.config({cloud_name: 'name',api_key: '***********',api_secret: '***********'})
  });
}
```

The request payload is :

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryU4RVLNgyBJWMIyd6
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="api_key"

***************
------WebKitFormBoundaryU4RVLNgyBJWMIyd6
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="signature"

e9631cd9db0b576c9756285ca4a94b386281121c
------WebKitFormBoundaryU4RVLNgyBJWMIyd6
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="timestamp"

1438845000
------WebKitFormBoundaryU4RVLNgyBJWMIyd6
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"

data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAIAAAACACAYAAADDPmHLAAAABmJLR0QA/wD/AP+gvaeTAAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAAAAB3RJTUUH3wcXDwcsJpcKdQAAG0FJREFUeNrtfXl8ldW19rPWe04GIGgVxAGLt4MRrVMhIyEnCWKjmZASpVJxaPVqQnvrrdaqrViHtref2qsloP1sreCEURmSYAQkOYGQiaCoV6VcFVBUtA4QINN517p/RBF49wkJOcMLZv3Dj5Pk7L3Xevaa9tprA4P0tSY6kheXNGnKsR7RRBE5VQnHAUhQ1QQGEkBIUNAwEsQAskuJdxGhDUAbFG0g2gnCOzawcajseMvv9wcGAeBWmj2bU1e3niM2fAR8T4HTSDURzMeG4usFCLDibSVsJGCjqjSpx1vT8uLiTwYBEK3dnV1wBgmyiZAjCh8TjonwFFRUXmWiVSRYJUMC/ubq6p2DAAgjJecUn

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="err"

function (e){console.info(e)}
------WebKitFormBoundaryU4RVLNgyBJWMIyd6
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="res"

function (e){console.info(e)}
------WebKitFormBoundaryU4RVLNgyBJWMIyd6--
```

I invariably get

```
POST https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/name/image/upload 400 (Bad Request)
```

From Cloudinary server. I have a hard time figuring out what is wrong. Could i get help to find some hint ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `err` and `res` aren't params that should be passed as part of the `data-form-data`.
2. When you experience any errors, Cloudinary always returns the error's details under the `x-cld-error` HTTP header.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using nekojira packages that i found more simple for my humble use : 
[github repository here](https://github.com/nekojira/cloudinary-jquery-upload)

To configure :

**Client level**

```
$.cloudinary.config({ cloud_name: '****', api_key: '*****'})
```

**Server level**

```
cloudinary.config({ 
    cloud_name: '****', 
    api_key: '****', 
    api_secret: '*****' 
  });
```

**To implement**

In Cloudinary create a [unsigned tag](http://cloudinary.com/blog/direct_upload_made_easy_from_browser_or_mobile_app_to_the_cloud)

In your template:

```
<template name="cloudy">
    <form id="test" class="ui message"></form>
</template>
```

In you javascript meteor client file :

```
Template.cloudy.rendered = function() {

$("#test").append($.cloudinary.unsigned_upload_tag("my_unsigned_tag", { cloud_name: '****' },{ multiple: true }))
    .bind('cloudinarydone', function(e, data) {
         console.info("UPLOADED")
    }).bind('cloudinaryprogress', function(e, data) { 
         console.info(data.loaded,data.total)
    });
}
```